# UnsafeMutablePointer initialization

Tags: ios, swift3

```
1. let context = CGContext(...)
2. context.draw(...)
3. let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>(context.data) // error here
```

Using Swift 3, line 3 produces an error that says:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)'
```

Is there a way to convert `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` to any appropriate type that `UnsafeMutablePointer` accepts as a parameter upon initialization?

By the way, the class reference for `UnsafeMutablePointer` can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsafemutablepointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this will do the initialization.

```
    let ptr = context.data
    let data = ptr!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>.self).pointee
    let pixelBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>(data)
```